# Get associated properties as array - where a given property exists

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, left-join

I have a table `tbl_a`.

```
 id | name
----+-------
  1 | item1
  2 | item2
  3 | item3
```

I also have a table `tbl_aprops` which stores properties `prop` associated with items `a` from `tbl_a`.

```
 a_id | prop
------+------
    1 | xx
    1 | yy
    2 | xx
    2 | zz
    3 | yy
```

I wish to perform a `LEFT JOIN` where all the information from the left table `tbl_a` is returned along with the associated properties `prop` from `table_aprops` in an array in a new column called `props`. I wish to filter out items **not** associated with property 'yy' while still returning **all** associated properties `prop` from `tbl_aprops`.

```
 id | name  |   props
----+-------+-----------
  1 | item1 | {'xx','yy'}
  3 | item3 | {'yy'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to filter out items **not** associated with property 'yy' while still returning **all** associated properties prop from `tbl_aprops`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_a a
JOIN  (
   SELECT a_id AS id, array_agg(x.prop) AS props
   FROM   tbl_aprops y
   JOIN   tbl_aprops x USING (a_id)
   WHERE  y.prop = 'yy'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a9e63e8908fbc80688335d2486aae125)*

In the subquery `a`, aggregate arrays after filtering with `WHERE prop = 'yy'` and a self-join. Produces exactly one row per qualifying item. Then join to table `tbl_a`. Voilá.
Notably: **No** `LEFT JOIN` for this.

*For convenience* I renamed `a_id` to just `id` in the subquery, so I can join with `USING (id)`. That only returns a single copy of the column, and `SELECT *` returns what we need without redundant column.

For best performance, have an **index** on `tbl_aprops(prop, a_id)`.
And indexes on `tbl_aprops(a_id, prop)` (with inverted column sequence!) and `tbl_a(id)`. Consider:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Answer (score 0):

The following query can be used to achieve this:

```
SELECT z.*
FROM tbl_aprops b
JOIN (
  SELECT a.* AS id, array_agg(p.prop) props
  FROM tbl_a a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_aprops p
  ON a.id = p.a_id
  GROUP BY a.id) z
ON z.id = b.a_id
WHERE b.prop = 'yy';
```

I am however open to suggestions that improve the efficiency of this query.

Comment: The query does not yet return additional columns from `tbl_a` (only `name` in the demo).